# How to list all employees that come under a particular employee?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select * 
from IWIN..VW_EMPMASTER E 
where E.em_teamcd = 'C0015'
```

gives me:

```
C3892
C6331
```

which is list of employees which come immediately under `C0015`

```
Select * 
from IWIN..VW_EMPMASTER E 
where E.em_teamcd = 'C3892'
```

gives me list of all 14 employees which come immediately under  `C3892`

I want to get list of ALL employees which come under 'em_empid' `C0015` directly or indirectly.. and not just employees which come directly under him. How can I do so ?

Maximum level of hierarchy is 5.

Comment: This can be done with a recursive common table expression. But your question lacks the necessary information to be able to answer this. Please post the complete structure of that table. Especially how the "parent" and "child" rows are related. Your SQL contains a `em_teamcd` column yet you claim the id is actually stored in the column `em_empid`. Which is it?

Comment: [Recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) or 5 times self join (as max level is 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `em_teamcd`is the identifier for the manager and `em_empid`identifies employees (including managers) you can use a [recursive query using a common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I adapted this from an example in the documentation:

```
WITH Tree (em_empid, em_teamcd, level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.em_empid, e.em_teamcd, 0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.VW_EMPMASTER AS e
    WHERE em_teamcd = 'C0015'
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.em_empid, e.em_teamcd, Level + 1
    FROM dbo.VW_EMPMASTER AS e
    INNER JOIN Tree AS d ON e.em_teamcd = d.em_empid
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT * FROM Tree WHERE Level <= 5
```

The column `em_empid`will hold all employees that has `C0015`above them.

A sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f115/4) with some fake data.